# Exact matches with wildcard search + keyword analyzer

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I use a **wildcard** query on fields indexed with a **keyword analyzer**. I want to find the following document

```
{
  title: "JavaScript beginner course",
  url: "https://youtube.com/xyz"
}
```

with these queries: `*beginner course*` and `*youtube*` (`*` are wildcards). **This is working**.

When I search for `*Java*`, the document above will also match. That's fine. However, **I want to boost search results with exact word matches**. Meaning, a document with `Java` in the title should have a higher search score.

Problem is, the keyword analyzer doesn't index each word separately. But I need the keyword analyzer, because otherwise `*beginner course*` wouldn't match in the example above.

**Is there a way to achieve exact matching with wildcard search + a keyword analyzer?**

Answer (score 1):

By itself you can't boost full word matches in a wildcard query to my knowledge.

But you can always have another analyzer and another query in conjunction with your wildcard query. So you would have both **wildcard with lucene.keyword and "Java*" as well as text with lucene.standard and "Java" in one query**.